# ajax jquery .on click function get this id or parameter id-data or data-title-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the id of the div with class=ajax to the jquery function, but I don't manage to do so.

In the console I either get undefined or nothing at all.

```
<div class="ajax" id="id" data-id="id" data-title-id="id">
```

to call the function I fake a click:

```
$(".ajax").triggerHandler( "click" );
```

this is the function:

```
$('.ajax').on('click', function () {
// var id = $(this).data("id"); // undefined
// var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); // undefined
// var id = $(this).attr("data-title-id"); // undefined
var id = this.id; // doesn't return anything

console.log(id);
})
```

EDIT:

Probably I should mention, I have a:

```
ev.stopPropagation();
```

right after the $(".ajax").triggerHandler( "click" );

and the problem is no the trigger, which works fine with trigger, triggerHandler, and also with .click

The problem is that I don't manage to pass the id of the div that contains the "ajax" class to the jquery function.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$(".ajax").trigger( "click" );` or `$(".ajax")[0].click();`

Comment: @Satpal, the click part works that's not the problem I just updated the question, thanks for your hints

Answer (score 0):

the function should be :

```
$('.ajax').on('click', function () {


var id = $(this).attr('id') 

if(window.console){
console.log("\id = " +id);

}
})
```

**EDIT :**
`triggerHandler` should be used only after the event handler has been attached, After the above function, add the following line:

```
$(".ajax").triggerHandler( "click" );
```

Comment: I tried your code but comes as undefined also, any ideas? thanks